# CruiseControl.NET email publisher problem

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to set up ccnet to:

1. Send mail to committers after each build (regardless of the status)
2. Send mail to all other developers when the build breaks or is fixed

With every new version of CCNet the email publisher gets refactored (and supposedly improved), but I still have the same problem: *only the committers get notified - if the build breaks, other developers don't get the email message*. So either I don't get the system, or there is a long-unfixed bug in the email publisher.

I'm using the v1.4.4.83. My example configuration (I removed the irrelevant stuff):

```
<email 
    includeDetails="true">
    <users>
        <user name="user1" address="user1@mail.com" group="developers" /> 
        <user name="user2" address="user2@mail.com" group="developers" /> 
    </users>
    <groups>
            <group name="developers">
                <notifications>
                    <notificationType>Failed</notificationType>
                    <notificationType>Fixed</notificationType>
                </notifications>
            </group>
    </groups>
    <modifierNotificationTypes>
        <NotificationType>Always</NotificationType>
    </modifierNotificationTypes>
</email>
```

Comment: This looks like a feature no one before needed, could you please post it to http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET ?

Comment: The funny thing is - this was actually possible in previous versions of CCNet (1.3 from what I remember).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this does what you want (admittedly, a year after your question).

NB: We use SVN, with a `<svn>` block. In CC.NET 1.4.xx, `<email>` blocks support regular expressions to work out email addresses from SVN usernames. It should work with other source control blocks, but I haven't used anything but SVN.

We have something like the following in our `<publishers>` block (I've modified it to match your spec):

```
<email ... includeDetails="true">
  <!-- Developers get an email whenever the build status changes -->
  <users>
    <user name="Dev1" group="developer" address="dev1@ourcompany.com" />
    <user name="Dev2" group="developer" address="dev2@ourcompany.com" />
  </users>
  <groups>
    <group name="developer" notification="change" />
  </groups>

  <!-- Committers get an email for every build they commit code for -->
  <converters>
    <regexConverter find="$" replace="@ourcompany.com" />
  </converters>
  <modifierNotificationTypes>
    <NotificationType>always</NotificationType>
  </modifierNotificationTypes>
</email>
```

So, dev1@ourcompany.com and dev2@ourcompany.com will get an email whenever the build status changes, and [svnuser]@ourcompany.com will get an email when the build they've committed code for finishes building.

NB: if the build fails, svn users who have committed code since it last succeeded will continue to get further emails each time a build finishes until the build is fixed.

Comment: I'll accept your answer although I'm not able to test the solution - we switched to Hudson CI a while ago. We simply grew tired of configuration XML soup and regression bugs.

Comment: @Igor: Hudson CI? I haven't heard of that before. Although I know CC pretty well, it does have many down sides! I may take a look at it some time, cheers for the mention.

Comment: http://hudson-ci.org/ ... much friendlier than CC. It's Java based, but it does have a few .NET-oriented plugins. And it has a proper GUI :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want... we're running version 1.4.3 so YMMV. Devs get emails only when there is a change in fixed/failed status, while the PM gets an email every time there's a build.

```
<groups>
   <group name="Always">
        <name>Always</name>
        <notification>Always</notification>
    </group>
    <group name="developers">
        <name>developers</name>
        <notification>Change</notification>
    </group>
</groups>
<users>
    <user name="dev1">
        <address>...</address>
        <group>developers</group>
        <name>...</name>
    </user>
    <user name="pm1">
        <address>...</address>
        <group>Always</group>
        <name>...</name>
    </user>
    <user name="dev2">
        <address>...</address>
        <group>developers</group>
        <name>...</name>
    </user>
    <user name="dev3">
        <address>...</address>
        <group>developers</group>
        <name>...</name>
    </user>
</users>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<email from="CruiseControlBuild@xxxxxxxx.com" mailhost="xxxxxxxx.com" includeDetails="True">
            <users>
                <user name="Dev Staff" group="group1" address="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
                <user name="QA Staff" group="group1" address="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
            </users>
            <groups>
                <group name="group1" notification="always"/>
            </groups>
            <modifierNotificationTypes>
                <NotificationType>Always</NotificationType>
            </modifierNotificationTypes>
        </email>
```

This works, but be careful. Sending every developer an email for every build in a continuous system is begging to have your emails ignored. The only email I send to everyone is the nightly installer build.

Comment: Alex, I DON'T want to send an email for EVERY build to EVERY developer. I think I made that clear at the beginning of the question (see 1. and 2.).

Comment: not only would the emails be ignored, but depending on your SMTP host rules, it may get you blocked or filtered at the ISP level!