# CruiseControl.Net Publisher email failing to send e-mail

Tags: smtp, cruisecontrol.net, email-publisher

So here's my problem:

I cannot seem to be able to configure CruiseControl.NET to send out an e-mail to me when a build occurs ( I want it to **always** send me an e-mail, as specified below)

I copied the example from the documentation and filled it in with my own values. 
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Email+Publisher

Here's the relevant section of ccnet.config below

```
<publishers>
      <merge>
        <files>
          <file>C:\Build\Temp\*.xml</file>
        </files>
      </merge>
      <xmllogger logDir="buildlogs" />
      <statistics>
        <statisticList>
          <statistic />
        </statisticList>
      </statistics>

      <email includeDetails="TRUE" mailhostUsername="user" mailhostPassword="password" useSSL="TRUE">
        <from>me@mycompany.com</from>
        <mailhost>mail.mycompanysmtpserver.com</mailhost>
        <users>
            <user name="MyName Lastname" group="buildmaster" address="me@mycompany.com" />
        </users>
        <groups>
            <group name="buildmaster">
              <notifications>
                <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
              </notifications>
            </group>
        </groups>
        <modifierNotificationTypes>
            <NotificationType>Failed</NotificationType>
            <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
        </modifierNotificationTypes>
        <subjectSettings>
            <subject buildResult="StillBroken" value="Build is still broken for {CCNetProject}" />
        </subjectSettings>
      </email>

    </publishers>
```

I have had a successful CruiseControl.NET server configured for some time, and it successfully updates people through CCTray, but I need to add e-mail support as well.

I've already looked at the relevant StackOverflow articles like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031011/cruisecontrol-net-email-publisher-problem) and m[any more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cruisecontrol.net+e-mail+publisher) and tried my hand at googling the solution but I dont know what I could be doing wrong. The only other thing that I'd like to validate is that I can send/receive e-mails using my username/password with the SMTP server I received from IT

**EDIT:** I confirmed thru telnet that the SMTP server is working properly by following steps 1-5 in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119).

Anyone have any ideas as to why I'm getting this problem, or how to troubleshoot it further?

Comment: Are you using IIS SMTP?  If so, its flaky at times.  Have you enabled SMTP logging?

SERVER->Properties->Enable logging

If the logs don't show up, your smtp is misconfigured, most likely the security settings.  If thats the case, post the IIS level you are running.

Comment: Serapth,
Thanks for the hint! 
I have virtually no control over the SMTP server, but based on your comment I decided to use my personal Gmail account and see if my build server e-mails would go through. It indeed worked with my g-mail account, meaning something is screwed up with my company's SMTP server.  

To confirm, you mention the Server -> Properties -> Enable logging - I should do this on the SMTP server, not the build server, correct?  That is, that this problem probably has has nothing to do with the IIS level on my build server?

Comment: Yes, assuming you are using Windows Server build in SMTP server and not a solution like Exchange.  The problem is, the SMTP server is actually part of IIS and in order to enable logging, or change permission settings, you need to have access to that server.  The most likely problem is the SMTP server needs to be configured to allow your server to send mail through it, depending on how it was configured by your network guys.  Most likely they need to add your servers IP addresses to the allowed list or they need to add your domain user to the permissions list.  Either way, you need access.

Comment: As a suggestion, if you have full access to your development server, why not attempt to configure SMTP locally?  Its added via Programs And Features, but if you are running Windows Server 2008, you actually need to install IIS 6 compatibility, as MS haven't updated SMTP to work natively with IIS 7.

Comment: Oh, and no, the problem has nothing to do with the IIS level on your build server.  IIS level is just a factor in terms of getting SMTP installed/configured, especially on Server 2008.  Its a common point for people to get tripped up at, nothing more.

Comment: @Serapth: I've been able to contact IT and they might be able to help me "fix" the STMP server so it is working. 

If this doesn't work I will probably investigate using the server as an SMTP server. Thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was an SMTP server issue, not an issue with CruiseControl.net

See the comments under my post for more information. Testing using my personal gmail account resulted in a successful e-mail.