# Cruise Control.Net 1.5 + Visual Source Safe + MSBuild.exe

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am trying Cruise Control.net 1.5 integrate to Visual Source Safe.

Could any one share with me step by step (configuration for Build+Email+Triggers+Publish)to do cruise control.net with Visual Source safe.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you looked at the ccnet documentation? http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Visual+Source+Safe+Source+Control+Block

Comment: I tried that one but issue is that once this particular portion is excuted. files is not getlatest in local folder.only its showing "No Modification" on Command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at ["How to Hook Up a VS.NET 2005 Solution with CruiseControl.NET in a few minutes."](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/pages/How-to-Hook-Up-a-VS.NET-2005-Solution-With-CruiseControl.NET-in-a-Few-Minutes.aspx) ?

The configuration file (for vss) looks like this:

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <project name="Johans Test System">
    <sourcecontrol type="vss" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="true">
      <executable>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\ss.exe</executable>
      <project>$/JohansTestSystem.root</project>
      <username>Johan</username>
      <password></password>
      <ssdir>c:\vss\</ssdir>
      <workingDirectory>C:\CI\</workingDirectory>
      <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
    </sourcecontrol>

    <triggers>
      <intervalTrigger seconds="60" />
    </triggers>

    <tasks>
      <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>c:\CI\JohansTestSystem</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>JohansTestSystem.sln</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
        <targets>Build</targets>
        <timeout>15</timeout>
        <logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
      </msbuild>
      <nunit path="C:\nunit\bin\nunit-console.exe">
        <assemblies>
          <assembly>C:\CI\JohansTestSystem\Johan.Test\bin\Debug\Johan.Test.dll</assembly>
        </assemblies>
      </nunit>
    </tasks>

    <publishers>
      <xmllogger />
    </publishers>

  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

[Email blocks documentation](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Email_Publisher) is pretty straightforward.

Here is CruiseControl.NET's example:

```
 1<email mailport="25" includeDetails="TRUE" mailhostUsername="smtpuser" mailhostPassword="smtppassword" useSSL="FALSE">
 2  <from>buildmaster@mycompany.com</from>
 3  <mailhost>smtp.mycompany.com</mailhost>
 4  <users>
 5    <user name="BuildGuru" group="buildmaster" address="buildguru@mycompany.com" />
 6    <user name="JoeDeveloper" group="developers" address="joedeveloper@thoughtworks.com" />
 7  </users>
 8  <groups>
 9    <group name="developers">
10      <notifications>
11        <notificationType>Failed</notificationType>
12        <notificationType>Fixed</notificationType>
13      </notifications>
14    </group>
15    <group name="buildmaster">
16      <notifications>
17        <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
18      </notifications>
19    </group>
20  </groups>
21  <converters>
22    <regexConverter find="$" replace="@TheCompany.com" />
23  </converters>
24  <modifierNotificationTypes>
25    <NotificationType>Failed</NotificationType>
26    <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
27  </modifierNotificationTypes>
28  <subjectSettings>
29    <subject buildResult="StillBroken" value="Build is still broken for {CCNetProject}" />
30  </subjectSettings>
31  <xslFiles>
32    <file>xsl\header.xsl</file>
33    <file>xsl\compile.xsl</file>
34    <file>xsl\unittests.xsl</file>
35    <file>xsl\modifications.xsl</file>
36  </xslFiles>
37  <attachments>
38    <file>C:\Data\AFile.txt</file>
39    <file>Relative.txt</file>
40  </attachments>
41</email>
```

and of course if you want to send via gmail, that's cool too:

> GMail For sending mail via gmail :
>   * mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" 
>   * mailport="587" 
>   * mailhostUsername="xxx.yyy@gmail.com" 
>   * mailhostPassword="yourpassword" 
>   * useSSL="TRUE"

You should probably also check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031011/cruisecontrol-net-email-publisher-problem) about CC.NET email publishing: